# Почему при использовании fgets() я не могу получить данные из stdin?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "end.h"

#define MAX_LENGTH 21

struct Employee {
    char lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char title[MAX_LENGTH];
    int salary;
};

int main() {
    int i, j, number;
    printf("%s", "Enter the number of employees: "); fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &number);
    struct Employee employee[number];

    for (i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the last name: "); fflush(stdout);
        fgets(employee[i].lastName, sizeof(employee[i].lastName), stdin);
        if (strlen(employee[i].lastName) == 0)
            break;
        printf("Enter the first name: "); fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%20s", employee[i].firstName);
        printf("Enter the title: "); fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%20s", employee[i].title);
        printf("Enter the salary: "); fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &employee[i].salary);
        if (i < number-1)
            printf("%s\n", "The next one!");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < number; ++j)
    {
        printf("{%s,%s,%s,%d}\n", 
            employee[j].lastName, 
            employee[j].firstName, 
            employee[j].title, 
            employee[j].salary);
    } 
    separate();
    return 0;
}
```

[Скриншот из терминала](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dylfr.png)

Comment: the calls to `fflush(stdout)` after the calls to `printf()` are not necessary.  The following call to `scanf()` will force a flush of the stdout buffer

Comment: the function: `fgets()` inputs/saves that newline `\n` into the buffer before appending the NUL byte, so this line: `if (strlen(employee[i].lastName) == 0)` will always fail.   Suggest checking for '\n' as the first char in the lastName[] aray

Comment: regarding this kind of line: ` scanf("%20s", employee[i].firstName);`  the function; `scanf()` will not read across any white space when using a '%s' format specifier,  However, a space in the format string will read across white space,  Suggest: ` scanf("% 20s", employee[i].firstName);`

Comment: This line: `scanf("%d", &employee[i].salary);` (as will the inputting of the `number`), will leave the trailing white space '\n' in the stdin stream.   Then the call to `fgets()` will fail because all it will read is '\n'.   Suggest, before the call to `fgets()`, inside the loop,  `int ch; while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch );` to empty the stdin stream.

Comment: for each of the `"%20s"` format strings, change to `" %20s"` (note the leading space) so any leftover white space will be consumed

Answer (score 3):

В этих предложениях

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

и

```
scanf("%d", &employee[i].salary);
```

функция `scanf` читает символы до разделителя, которым в частности является символ новой строки, который остается в буфере ввода. Поэтому при очередной итерации цикла, когда используется функция `fgets`, то она читает все символы до символа новой строки, включая и сам символ новой строки. То есть будет прочитан только этот символ новой строки (и, возможно, пробелы перед этим символом, если пользователь их ввел после введенных чисел), который остался в буфере ввода после вышеуказанных предложений.

Вам надо его удалять из буфера ввода.

Проще всего было бы читать все данные, используя функцию `fgets` Для числовых данных вы могли бы применять функцию `atoi` к прочитанной строке.